# Where is Jon Snow's raiding party going after climbing the Wall from the Northside?

Tags: game-of-thrones

I'm confused: after climbing the wall, where is Jon Snow's party going?

They talk about 'when they attack Castle Black', but Castle Black is *right* against the Wall on south side... yet they are clearly traveling some distance through ever greener country.

If they already made it past the wall without incident,  why are they even thinking of going back to Castle Black?  *And* (more importantly), *where* are they headed first?

They seem to be 'on their way' to Castle Black,  but they're obviously moving south.

Comment: If you want book related answers you can also tag it [a-song-of-ice-and-fire]

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: As of now your tag suggests answers from the show canon only. If you want answers from the book canon you need to include the tag [a-song-of-ice-and-fire]

Comment: But it's the show I'm asking about.

Comment: I simply hoped someone might explain where they are headed,  as they are clearly moving south from the wall,  yet they are talking about attacking the wall  (which they've already climbed and passed without incident).

Comment: Hi Gina, welcome to the site. Don't worry about people editing your question, it's not a criticism, everyone makes minor errors and this site is a bit perfectionistic about such things. We're not a forum, we try to be *the* definitive detailed answer so that in future if someone thinking the same as you googles the same question they'll find a great answer. Don't be surprised if it takes a day or two to get an answer but when they come they'll usually be really thorough. If you want some quick chat you might prefer the GoT forums, there are lots of them and they're mostly pretty good

Comment: My edits were not meant to dishearten you, sorry if it looked that way. Here you can add italics by using Stars * or underscores _ on either side of a word or a sentence. It is common for this website for users to edit questions to fix spelling, grammar, and other issues. Regarding your other concern: I would answer, but I am simply not versed enough in the world of _GoT_.

Comment: That of course is perfectly fine! Some new users end up deciding they want both canons but if you only want the show canon that's fine too. I believe our resident expert is currently in bed. But his competitor is awake and I'm sure will be here to answer your question shortly.

Comment: Thank you,  all of you,  for all the informative answers!

Comment: (And thanks for explaining how to produce italics without the benefit of a keyboard!)

Answer (score 12):

They are going to Castle Black, but it's slightly round-about because they are part of a two-pronged attack and have to circle around behind.

From the map below you can see that they climbed the wall roughly between Greyguard and Stonedoor. Once over the wall, they'll need to move away from it for two reasons.

1. To avoid any Night's Watch traveling between The Shadow Tower and Castle Black.
2. Because they need to live off the land as they wait for the signal to attack.

Indeed, the attack on Castle Black comes a full 13 episodes later, no mean amount of time in-universe. So the wildings travel south to a slightly more habitable climate to wait for the attack.

I think the amount of green they see is more a byproduct of the magic in The Wall than an indication of how far they traveled. The Gift is only 50 leagues  (roughly two days walk) from Wall to border, so they couldn't have gone that far, even if they had traveled to the very edge. We know that they appeared in Moletown, so odds are they spent most of the journey within 5-10 leagues of the wall.

[image]
<sup>From the *Beyond the Wall* map in *Lands of Ice and Fire*</sup>

Comment: That's a good point about living off the land, and of course in the show we see that their "living off the land" includes raiding some farms and homesteads, so they need to go far enough south to reach these

Comment: Thank you! !!   This makes complete sense.  I was really confused!  Thanks again.

Comment: @GinaPaiano - Excellent! If you feel it answers your question satisfactorily, feel free to click that checkmark next to the answer and give it an upvote.